Methods to add role attributes to tokens in Keycloak
I'm using Keycloak version 25.0.4.
I created roles for Clients and added Attributes as key-value pairs to those roles.
However, in the token, only the roles are passed as an array, and the Attribute values for the roles are not included.
Why is this happening? Is there a way to add these Attributes to the token?
I tried to create a mapper, but it seems there isn't an appropriate mapper type available."
